# Transit or tourist visa for Qatar: impossible to get at the moment?

Tags: transit-visas, tourist-visas, qatar

Is it correct that you can only exit the airport in Doha at the moment if:

- you either don't need a visa
- are eligible for a visa on arrival
- or had a FIFA world cup 2022 ticket (Hayya card)

I cannot find a way how a Filipino citizen (living in a Schengen country) could apply for a transit or tourist visa.

Comment: Have you checked the information here https://visitqatar.com/intl-en/practical-info/visas?

Comment: Why do you think you can't get a visa? You don't say what country you live in but e.g. the Qatari embassy in Berlin [certainly says they issue visas](https://berlin.embassy.qa/en/services/consular-services).

Comment: We are living in Switzerland. When you check https://visitqatar.com/intl-en/practical-info/visas, the only available Visa for a Filipino living in Switzerland is a transit visa, but all links for registration are dead. For me, it looks the visa application websites were disabled because of COVID and they forgot to enable them again. Most tourists don't need a visa or can get in on arrival. @mlc is probably right that a Qatari embassy can issue physical visas, but we will then probably just visit another country.